# Box Jenkins Autocorrelation in Octave

Tags: octave

I have the following 50 samples vector:

```
a =

   0.0070398
   0.0071569
   0.0071597
   0.0071614
   0.0071254
   0.0071286
   0.0071043
   0.0071640
   0.0071707
   0.0071813
   0.0071288
   0.0070965
   0.0071268
   0.0071027
   0.0070675
   0.0070540
   0.0070033
   0.0069686
   0.0069367
   0.0069110
   0.0069406
   0.0069742
   0.0069297
   0.0069140
   0.0068838
   0.0069168
   0.0069261
   0.0069110
   0.0068610
   0.0068222
   0.0067937
   0.0067714
   0.0067458
   0.0067084
   0.0066542
   0.0066503
   0.0066675
   0.0066913
   0.0066844
   0.0066897
   0.0066587
   0.0066329
   0.0066484
   0.0066282
   0.0066080
   0.0065814
   0.0065367
   0.0065021
   0.0064948
   0.0064713
```

I would like to calculate the autocorrelation of the vector. I have written Box Jenkins formula as follows:

[image: Box Jenkins autocorrelation]

And implemented the function in Octave:

```
function autocorr(y, tau)

    y_bar = mean(y);
    T = length(y);

    # NUMERATOR
    numerator = 0;
    for t = (tau + 1):T
        numerator += (y(t)-y_bar)*(y(t-tau)-y_bar);
    endfor

    # DENOMINATOR
    denominator = 0;
    for t = 1:T
        denominator += (y(t)-y_bar)**2;
    endfor

    retval = numerator/denominator  # NOTE THAT 1/T IS PRESENT IN BOTH NUMERATOR AND DENOMINATOR


endfunction
```

Now if I do:

```
octave:41> autocorr(a,1)
retval =  0.94683
```

I get 0.94683 instead of 1.

1. Is it correct to expect 1?
2. What could be do to reduce the error in Octave?
3. Is there any available function/package in Octave to calculate this?

Comment: in the formula is Tau 1 or 0 ? when 0 you should get 1, but with 1 the result is less than 1

Comment: Right, I was using wrong Tau for 1. With 0 you get 1.